# Reduce $\left\lvert \frac{(a+ib)^2 e^{ia+b}-(a-ib)^2 e^{ia-b}}{4abi} \right\rvert ^2$, expressing the result with hyperbolic functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

I have to reduce:

$$\left\lvert \frac{(a+ib)^2 e^{ia+b}-(a-ib)^2 e^{ia-b}}{4abi} \right\rvert ^2$$

$a$ and $b$ have to be real, and I have to express the answer in hyperbolic functions.

My guess is that I have to use the next formulas: 
$\cosh x = \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$ and  $\sinh x = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}$

but I also see that the denominator is two complex numbers in polar form.

**Edit:** I rewrote $(a+ib)^2$ and $(a-ib)^2$ in polar form
 $$\left\lvert \frac{(a^2+b^2)e^{2iϕ} e^{ia+b}-(a^2+b^2)e^{-2iϕ} e^{ia-b}}{4abi} \right\rvert ^2$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is literally what you have to do.

(1) Simplify by noting that the absolute of some of the terms are unity,

$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \frac{(a+ib)^2 e^{ia+b}-(a-ib)^2 e^{ia-b}}{4abi} \right\rvert ^2
&=\left\lvert \frac{e^{ia}}{4abi}\right\rvert ^2~\left\lvert (a+ib)^2 e^{b}-(a-ib)^2 e^{-b}\right\rvert ^2\\
&=\frac{1}{16a^2b^2}~\left\lvert (a+ib)^2 e^{b}-(a-ib)^2 e^{-b}\right\rvert ^2\\
\end{align}
$$

(2) expand and collect the real and imaginary parts

$$
\begin{align}
\left\lvert (a+ib)^2 e^{ia+b}-(a-ib)^2 e^{ia-b}\right\rvert ^2
&=\left\lvert (a^2-b^2) (e^{b}-e^{-b})+2abi(e^{b}+e^{-b}) \right\rvert ^2\\
&=\left\lvert (a^2-b^2) 2\sinh b+2abi 2\cosh b \right\rvert ^2\\
&=\sqrt{((a^2-b^2) 2\sinh b)^2+(2ab 2\cosh b)^2}^2\\
&=(a^2-b^2)^2 4\sinh^2 b+16a^2b^2\cosh^2 b
\end{align}
$$

So that finally,

$$\left\lvert \frac{(a+ib)^2 e^{ia+b}-(a-ib)^2 e^{ia-b}}{4abi} \right\rvert ^2=\frac{(a^2-b^2)^2 \sinh^2 b}{4a^2b^2}+\cosh^2 b$$

I have verified this solution numerically for arbitrary (random) values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of hints:

1- $|e^{i \theta}|^2=1$.

2- $a+ib = r e^{i \phi}$, and $a-ib = r e^{-i \phi}$.

Using these hints, solving the question should be easy.